# Query is taking lesser time in it's second execution in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT * FROM TAB_EXAMPLE
```

First time it takes 3 seconds for some table but second time it takes 1 second. Why?

If SQL Server creates some query execution plans for query that have been executed once, how do I dispose these plans?

Comment: DBCC FREEPROCCACHE will do it for all plans in the cache. But don't forget to clear your buffer pools and storage controller caches and other implementation details, too! Do a cold boot.

Comment: @ta.speot.is : can you provide any example ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you execute the query at the first time, it goes in the Sql Server cache, so next executions are more fast.

If you want to clean cache, I use these two commands:

```
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
```

The first clean the cache, the second clean related buffers.

Comment: No effect in time after cleaning cache and buffers. if any other thing that also needs to clean up, please suggest ?

Comment: try this too: DBCC FLUSHPROCINDB(db_id) I've found this: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/23/sql-server-stored-procedure-clean-cache-and-clean-buffer/